# Awk instead of join

Tags: join, awk

I know this question might be answered many times before, but I can not adopt the answers to my question, since I do not know how to read the awk code(s) and, unfortunately, since am on a deadline would not have time to study it by myself.

I need to find an awk solution  for joining two files based on columns , to be used instead of join. The two files could have any number of columns (actually I'm going to use it in several occasions), and I'm going to match nth column of the first with nth column of the second one. Please explain which part is going to be changed for new uses (i.e. for indicating the columns that are going to be matched).

An example (but the files might be much longer):

file 1:

`7A5    miR1
A2LD1   miR2
A2MP1   mirR3
A4GALT  miR4`

and file 2:

`1559361_at      7A5
1566764_at      7A5
229819_at       A1BG
221217_s_at     A2BP1
235070_at       A2BP1
232422_at       A2LD1
237869_at       A2LD1`

and I expect to get:

`1559361_at 7A5 miR1
1566764_at  7A5 miR1
232422_at   A2LD1   miR2
237869_at   A2LD1   miR2`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, tell me if I'm right: (1) you always have *two* files, say `tags` and `data` (2) in `tags` you have a list of, tags, *one per line*, (3) in `data` you have many multi-column, multi-field records, and you want to pick the records which `n`-th field matches one of the tags, with `n` specified by the user of your script.

Comment: 1) There are always two files. 2) the 'tags' file can be single- or multi-column, just like 'data' which could be any 3) yes I'm looking for matching fiels. It's like 'join -1 n -2 n' 'tags' 'data'. Thank you

Comment: If `tags` is multi-column, do you want to match on all columns or on a specific one? (can I say that you question was rather poor?)

Comment: Could you please edit your question to reflect our discussion?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I edited it. Please tell me again if it's not clear yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to build a hash/array with the contents of file1, and just check for the existence of an entry in the hash when running through file2;

```
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1]=1; next} {if(h[$2]) print $0}' file1 file2
```

`NR==FNR {h[$1]=1; next}` just takes column 1 from file1 and uses it as a key in a hash with value 1. That is, all values in file1 will be entered as keys into the hash with value 1.

`{if(h[$2]) print $0}` will go through file2 and just print all rows where the second column exists in the hash.

Comment: It does work, but replaces \t with \s. I could resolve that with sed however, thanks.

Comment: @Amateur You could just replace the `print $1, $2` with `print $0` to print the exact row unchanged if the separator is a problem. Updated the answer with that.

Comment: It does work now, and it's I guess is pretty straightforward, thank you. Sorry for not having reputation to vote for it.

Comment: @Amateur You can still mark one of the answers as accepted using the checkmark at the voting buttons. That will allow others with similar problems to find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
% cat pick_on_col
awk -v tcol=$1 -v dcol=$2 '
  NR==FNR {tags[$tcol]=1; next}t.
          {if($dcol in tags)print}' "$3" "$4"
% sh pick_on_col 1 2 tags data
1559361_at      7A5
1566764_at      7A5
232422_at       A2LD1
237869_at       A2LD1
%
```

you may want to swap `$2` and `$3` in the script as well as `tags` and `data` on the invocation to better fit your perceived semantic (isn't it a bit obscure? what I mean is, if you want to use `... data tags` on the command line, because it fits better yourmental model of the operations, you have to swap the parameters on the `awk` invocation because, of course, the `tags` file *must* be read before `data`).

#### *Edit*

I modified the number of parameters to take into account a new request.

Comment: I can not simply copy and paste this into the shell, right? I tried so, but I guess it's going to be used as an awk script.

Comment: If you're going to use this procedure once or twice, you can paste it at the prompt, substituting the file names and the column numbers for the shell parameters `$1` to `$4`. OTOH, if this is a procedure to be used routinely, it's way better to use a script.  Nitpicking, not an `awk` script, but a shell script that uses `awk`...

Comment: If this is to be used routinely, _after your deadline_ you should process the command line using a set of options, as in `pick -from data 2 -using tags 1` or, indifferently, `pick -using tags 1 -from data 2` so that there is lesser risk of confusion for the user.